# Custom Dependency Property Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement exception

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm working on a `UserControl` that derives from `TextBox`.

I have Custom `DependencyProperty HelperText` like so:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty HelperTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("HelperText", typeof(ICTextBoxHelperText), typeof(ICTextBox));
public ICTextBoxHelperText HelperText
{
    get { return (ICTextBoxHelperText)GetValue(HelperTextProperty); }
    set { SetValue(HelperTextProperty, value); }
}
```

that is class type `ICTextBoxHelperText` and have a couple of properties i need in the UI.

```
public class ICTextBoxHelperText : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DefaultProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Default", typeof(string), typeof(ICTextBoxHelperText));
    public static string GetDefault(DependencyObject d) => (string)d.GetValue(DefaultProperty);
    public static void SetDefault(DependencyObject d, string value) { d.SetValue(DefaultProperty, value); }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty InvalidProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Invalid", typeof(string), typeof(ICTextBoxHelperText));
    public static string GetInvalid(DependencyObject d) => (string)d.GetValue(InvalidProperty);
    public static void SetInvalid(DependencyObject d, string value) { d.SetValue(InvalidProperty, value); }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValidatedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Validated", typeof(string), typeof(ICTextBoxHelperText));
    public static string GetValidated(DependencyObject d) => (string)d.GetValue(ValidatedProperty);
    public static void SetValidated(DependencyObject d, string value) { d.SetValue(ValidatedProperty, value); }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty AutoValidatedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("AutoValidated", typeof(string), typeof(ICTextBoxHelperText));
    public static string GetAutoValidated(DependencyObject d) => (string)d.GetValue(AutoValidatedProperty);
    public static void SetAutoValidated(DependencyObject d, string value) { d.SetValue(AutoValidatedProperty, value); }
}
```

here's the UI implementation:

```
<!-- TextBox -->
<tx:ICTextBox x:Name="icTextBox"
              Width="240"
              Margin="0,20,0,0"
              Padding="0"
              VerticalAlignment="Center">

    <!-- Helper Text -->
    <tx:ICTextBox.HelperText>
        <tx:ICTextBoxHelperText Default="{Binding ElementName=icTextBox, Path=Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                Invalid="Invalid"
                                Validated="Validated"
                                AutoValidated="AutoValidated"/>
    </tx:ICTextBox.HelperText>
</tx:ICTextBox>
```

Static values for the `ICTextBoxHelperText` works as intended and updates UI.

The problem is with the Binding. It simply dont work and I have this XAML binding exception `Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element`.

As I understand it must be the problem with no `DataContext` for this `ICTextBoxHelperText`, but `HelperText` IS declared inside `FrameworkElement` which is my Control that derives from `TextBox`.

Is this even possible to have a `DependencyProperty` that is Type of `DependencyObject`? I did so, so i would have some nice grouping of `DependencyProperties` of similar Type, instead of one houndred loose `DependencyProperties` in the `UserControl`.

Comment: For attached properties like that of your ICTextBoxHelperText  class, you must use `DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached`.

Comment: thank's for the comment, turned out i got that mixed as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What appears unusual to me is how you implement your Custom Dependency object class `ICTextBoxHelperText`. You register them as normal dependency properties, using Register, but the syntax for the Getters and Setters is an attached syntax (With method pairs of GetNNN/SetNNN instead of a normal property).

In XAML however, you seem to access them like one would do it with "normal" non-attached properties. Moreover there is no reason to make them attached properties. I'd recommend to rewrite the ICTextBoxHelperText  class and derive from `Freezable`, which is a lightweight implementation, guaranteed to link into the DataContext of the visual tree  - which an DependencyObject inheritance does not. And since your class just contains additional data but has no control template/ own visual presentation, it makes no sense to derive it from Control or UserControl.

So I'd recommend to rewrite ICTextBoxHelperText likes this and see if it solves the missing DataContext issue.

```
public class ICTextBoxHelperText : Freezable
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DefaultProperty =
          DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Default), typeof(string), typeof(ICTextBoxHelperText));
    
    public static string Default
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(DefaultProperty);
        set => SetValue(DefaultProperty, value); 
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty InvalidProperty =
          DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Invalid), typeof(string), typeof(ICTextBoxHelperText));

    public static string Invalid
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(InvalidProperty);
        set => SetValue(InvalidProperty, value); 
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValidatedProperty =
          DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Validated), typeof(string), typeof(ICTextBoxHelperText));

    public static string Validated
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(ValidatedProperty);
        set => SetValue(ValidatedProperty, value); 
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty AutoValidatedProperty =
          DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(AutoValidated), typeof(string), typeof(ICTextBoxHelperText));

    public static string AutoValidated
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(AutoValidatedProperty);
        set => SetValue(AutoValidatedProperty, value); 
    }

    // required override for Freezables
    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore() => new ICTextBoxHelperText();
}
```

Comment: you're most certainly right! thanks a lot. Rewriting the ICTextBoxHeler class helped